# Python - write at specific static column in file

Tags: python, file, whitespace

I need to be able to write at a specific column in a data file.

For example I have a string that has to be at column 40 in the file. I need to do this on multiple instances at various columns within the file.

The major Issue I am having is the following:

```
f.write(str(message)
f.write('%27s ' % (str(date))
```

message is a variable that ranges from length 1-10. If the length is 1 then the date is written at 27+1, if it is length of 10, then it is written at 27+10. I need the date to be written at exactly 27.

Comment: try `f.write('{:<27s}'.format(date))`

Comment: This is called "left-justified" output.  How did you miss this in the format documentation?

Comment: @Prune that doesn't help answer the question... thanks for trying anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figured this out... because I was writing the first string (message) without any formatting, the second would always be format based on the first.

To correct this I ensured that I ensured that the first write is at least of 10 characters and if not place white spaces for the rest:

```
f.write('%-10s ' % (str(message))
f.write('%27s ' % (str(date))
```